# deleting words which contain a certain phrase

Tags: bash, shell, text

im looking to delete all strings which contain a certain phrase (TCONS)

i have

```
TCONS_5424934 XLOC_2348324
catgcatgcatgcatgcatcgt

TCONS_33345 XLOC_2342323
catgcatgcatgcatgcatcgt
```

and I would like

```
XLOC_2348324
catgcatgcatgcatgcatcgt

XLOC_2342323
catgcatgcatgcatgcatcgt
```

I've tried using:

```
sed 's/\S*\(TCONS)\S*//g'
```

But that just deletes the whole line. How do I delete the whole word? Thanks

Comment: Running your sed command gives me an error (unmatched parenthesis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, GNU awk (and mawk) for that particular data:

```
$ awk -v RS="[ \n]" '!/TCONS/' file
XLOC_2348324
catgcatgcatgcatgcatcgt

XLOC_2342323
catgcatgcatgcatgcatcgt
```

It uses space and newline as record separators and basically breaks multiple words on one record as multiple records but your expected output allows it.

Answer (score 1):

A minor modification to your regular expression fixes the issue:

```
sed 's/\S*TCONS\S*\s*//g' file
```

This removes any number of non-spaces followed by TCONS, followed by any number of non-spaces, along with any trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can also express the same idea using character classes, the readability may/may not be any better, it's more a matter of taste, e.g.

```
sed 's/[^ \t]*TCONS[^ \t]*[ \t]*//g' file.txt
```

Basically it just looks for any string containing `TCONS` separated by either a `space` or `tab` (if present) and deletes the string along with any number of following spaces or tabs. The string and whitespace designators (`\S` and `\s`) are a very clean implementation as Tom shows, but the characters classes are also a viable option depending on what makes the most sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

do like this:
`sed 's/\b\s*\S*TCONS\S*\s*\b//g'`
\b in regular expressions match word boundaries. - so it'll delete only words with TCONS. it also delete all space characters before and after word, which substring is TCONS